# How many members will an AJAX chat be able to handle on a dedicated server before it overloads and becomes slow?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, chat

The details of the dedicated server (at the time the site starts) are as follows:

> OS: Linux CentOS
>
> CPU: Intel® Pentium 4 - 3.0 GHz
>
> RAM: 2 GB
>
> Storage: 2 x 120 GB hard drives
>
> Bandwidth: 500 GB per month

The AJAX chat is customly coded. It runs by sending and receiving Javascript commands to and from the database, and then evaluating them.

The chat refresh rate will probably be somewhere around 250ms, although the answers here may change the decision.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? ;-) Despite the specifics you've given, I doubt anyone can answer this for you. You'll have to do load testing against your given configuration. If you want *estimates*, you'll have to show your code (mostly the server-side code) and give an idea of a typical message and number of simultaneously-connected clients. But even then, the estimates will have such a wide error range as to be nearly meaningless.

Comment: Why don't you use node.js instead of having a db in the whole chat ordeal? The amount of chatters will depend on the amount of reads/writes that your db is able to handle. 300ish at the same time sounds like the capacity of such app (it's based on assumption that the read/write of the db will be the bottleneck - meaning hdd subsystem will actually restrict what's happening).

Comment: **@T.J. Crowder** I haven't actually coded the chatroom yet, I'm hoping to find ways to improve the performance though. **@Michael J.V.** Thanks for the advice, I might try your suggestion instead of the database. How much extra capacity will that idea be able to handle?

Comment: I'm not sure what reasons you have behind running a chatbox and how many users there will be on avarage, but I honestly think your problem is negligible. On the other hand, I do find WebSockets more useful than AJAX calls many times a second, considering bandwidth and ease of use.

Comment: @MichaelJ.V.
I am not expert on this topic and stumble upon this question because I am also implementing the same thing, I used SSE(server sent events) for the chatting app and it seems to work fine. I am using PHP-MySql. My server has 8Gb ram and good enough processor. I wanted to know if it is a good idea or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement browser-based chat application that's going to work on a relatively cheap server and be able to serve lots of users (say, 500 at a time) without crashing - your approach isn't effective.

Reasons: using DB to send JS to the clients who evaluate the code isn't really safe. It's also expensive. It also means that per every line of chat, you need to invoke the DB at least once.
That implies A LOT of I/O for the RDBMS.

If I were you, I'd check out [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Node.js allows you to write chat servers in JavaScript. The JS itself is not executed by the browser but by server.
It is **extremely** I/O efficient. It is also simple enough to allow a non-expert programmer to create proper chat apps.

Comment: Without database (doesn't matter if it is RDBMS or NoSQL) backend you won't be able to scale

Answer (score 0):

Using php for chat server isn't a good idea. Polling can give too much unnecessary load to server and doesn't scale well. In my opinion you should rethink whole architecture.

1. Polling is bad for chat - use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (long polling) instead
2. With comet you will need fast HTTP server which can handle thousands of concurrent connections - use [NGINX](http://nginx.org/)
3. PHP isn't good solution for chat app - process-like non-blocking solution is much better - look at [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) and their chat example
4. From now on you must decide whether you need to scale - if not you can write single-thread server on top of tornado and store all data in memory - of course you will need to delete old unneeded data. If you need to scale choose fast scalable datastore like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) - you'll have to poll database - but it will be single query for ALL clients connected to single tornado instance - not for every client

Facebook used (or still uses) this kind of architecture (using MySQL backend) for their needs

Comment: You say polling is bad for chat, then you suggest Comet but Comet actually uses polling for chatting. Kind of contradicting, don't you think? Otherwise - I agree on using NGINX as the HTTP server.

Comment: Comet uses long polling which is very different from standard polling. I would say there is enormous difference in the way they work, amount of databse queries they produce and amount of http request they're making. Conceptually they're completely different things - standard polling is "pull architecture" (client regularly asks server for data) and comet is "push architecture" (server decides when there is data for client and then pushes it to client)

Comment: Not really, in order for Comet based apps to retrieve data - the client has to specifically REQUEST the data. There's no actual push going on, it's all emulated. If it weren't the case WebSocket protocol wouldn't be defined and implemented, that's the only real full-duplex communication protocol for the browsers. Everything else is faking some sort of push mechanism, be it hidden iframe or what not - the bottom line is that the client (browser) periodically requests the resource from a server.

Comment: It's emulated BUT client doesn't have to periodically request data from server. In comet it makes AJAX request with infinite (or long enough) timeout and server decides when to return data for that request. Of course after completing request client have to start another, BUT: let's take this: 1000 clients, 200ms standard polling vs comet (with 200ms server side database polling), 5 seconds of time. Standard polling: 25000 HTTP requests, 25000 database queries. Comet: 1000-25000 HTTP requests (depends on actual data), 25 database queries (1000x less !!)

Comment: I'm not arguing what's more effective, bottom line is that it's all fake full-duplex communication that relies on the scheme of request-get data, which in the end - is long polling, regardless of whether you call it Comet or long polling or ajax chat or whatever buzzword you prefer. There ARE better implementations (Node.js or WebSockets protocol) that ARE proven to kick ass, much more than Comet based apps.

Comment: I don't want to argue too but you simply wrote that polling is the same as comet - and it isn't. WebSockets are new and aren't supported by older browsers. Node.js is simply server-side architecture which allows write fast non-blocking servers... same as Torando or Java NIO. I think that it's used to implement comet servers too :). I think that architecture used by facebook also deserves "proven" title :)